# Reasons why gzipped content might not be grokked by the browser

Tags: performance, http, browser, gzip, content-encoding

I'm attempting to serve static resources (css and javascript) as cached gzipped files for performance reasons.

The pages look gzipped when rendered, the Content-Encoding is correctly set to gzip according to LiveHTTPHeaders, and most importantly, the gzipped content is passing the GIDZipTest page (http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) just fine. Here's an example of the output from the test:

> **Web page compressed?  Yes**
>
> Compression type?     gzip
>
> Size, Markup (bytes)  18,286
>
> Size Compressed (bytes) 4,427
>
> Compression %     75.8

```
----
```

> **ResponseHeaders**
>
> status    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>
> pragma no-cache cache-control
>     private, max-age=86500
>
> expires Mon, 24 Aug 2009 04:34:14 GMT
>
> x-amz-acl public-read
>
> content-type  text/css
>
> content-md5   hqJaTBS3OzDFet/QHsd+ Qg==
>
> **content-encoding gzip**
>
> date  Wed, 19 Aug 2009 04:34:14 GMT
>
> server    -- my server --
>
> content-length    4427

The content-encoding header is in bold, and all the other headers are as expected.

The test page also shows the uncompressed page source, and it's always exactly as I'd expect it to be uncompressed, and I've even tried copying and pasting it to be rendered by the browser, and it works, so the problem must be in the actual step of recognizing that the page is gzipped and unzipping it.

And this isn't browser-specific. In FF, Webkit, and IE, these gzipped files are not being unzipped correctly. I've tried everything I can think of, but am genuinely stumped.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *cached gzipped files*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have something else gzipping the file a second time, but only for http 1.1 clients that list it in accept-encoding, like most browsers. GIDZipTest is sending http 1.0 requests, and gzipping to 1.0 clients is risky because http 1.0 doesn't have an accept-encoding field for clients to indicate which encodings they support, so it'd make sense for the second compressor (if there is one) to not gzip to 1.0 clients. If that's the case, GIDZipTest would get a single-gzipped response while browsers would get a double-gzipped (bad) response. That's just one possibility though. Rare, but it happens.

If that's not it, you really should give more information, like a url to a page exhibiting the problem.

Comment: You were correct, I am using Google App Engine and did not know that it automatically gzips, so by gzipping I was double gzipping the files.

Answer (score 0):

I've debugged a similar problem over the last couple of days. All html, css and js files in my project are gzip'ed. It worked fine until firefox 3.5 came along. Firefox 3.0 and IE 7+8 didn't have any issues. Oh and Opera 9+10 and Chrome choked on the encoding as well.

The symptoms were html and css files are correctly recognized, only js files had the problem. Firebug gives me this error message:

*Invalid Label*

*Content-Encoding: gzip\n*

The solution for me was to remove the doctype. I've tried loose and strict and neither works. But i would like to know what the proper doctype is.